# Appium with Android Emulator Proxy issue

Tags: android-studio, appium, appium-android

I am trying to automate a website test in Android Mobile Chrome browser using Appium but getting network error and the site is not reached.

My pc is under company proxy and managed by PAC script and VPN.

Setup:

Appium   1.21.0  (exe) running on http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub

Android Studio  AVD

in Emulator proxy is set to use Android Studio HTTP proxy, Auto detect proxy settings.

Driver:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                         capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
                         capabilities.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.21.0");
                            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Pixel_3a_API_30_x86");
                            capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
                            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.0");
                            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
                            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_VERSION, "90");
                        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new 
                                 URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

Console Log:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: New Command Timeout of 60 seconds expired. Try customizing the timeout using the 'newCommandTimeout' desired capability
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'VIRC5CG0149D6T', ip: '10.66.212.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: com.google.android.apps.chr..., appPackage: com.android.chrome, appiumVersion: 1.21.0, browserName: Chrome, browserVersion: 90, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appiumVersion: 1.21.0, browserName: Chrome, browserVersion: 90, device: Android, deviceName: Pixel_3a_API_30_x86, platformName: android, platformVersion: 11.0}, device: Android, deviceApiLevel: 30, deviceManufacturer: Google, deviceModel: sdk_gphone_x86_arm, deviceName: emulator-5554, deviceScreenDensity: 440, deviceScreenSize: 1080x2220, deviceUDID: emulator-5554, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, pixelRatio: 2.75, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 11, statBarHeight: 66, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 2022, left: 0, top: 66, width: 1080}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 86edde0e-a9fc-4e71-ab8b-f931820bdea0
```

Appium Log:

```
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "alwaysMatch": {
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     "appium:appiumVersion": "1.21.0",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     "browserName": "Chrome",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     "browserVersion": "83",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     "appium:device": "Android",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     "platformName": "android",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     "appium:deviceName": "Pixel_3a_API_30_x86",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     "appium:platformVersion": "11.0"
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   },
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "firstMatch": [
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m     {}
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   ]
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m }
[warn] [35m[BaseDriver][39m The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[warn] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   browserVersion
[warn] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   appiumVersion
[info] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Session created with session id: b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m We're going to run a Chrome-based session
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Chrome-type package and activity are com.android.chrome and com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main


[info] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Using device: emulator-5554
[info] [35m[ADB][39m Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Setting device id to emulator-5554
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 30
[info] [35m[ADB][39m Getting device platform version
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 11
'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting install status for io.appium.settings
'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[debug] [35m[Logcat][39m Starting logs capture with command: C:\\Users\\smtripat\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 logcat -v threadtime[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to local port 8200
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Checking app cert for C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk
[info] [35m[ADB][39m Using 'apksigner.jar' from 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\lib\apksigner.jar'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Starting apksigner: 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\\java.exe' -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar C:\\Users\\smtripat\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\30.0.3\\lib\\apksigner.jar verify --print-certs C:\\Users\\smtripat\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk[debug] 
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Starting apksigner: 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\\java.exe' -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar C:\\Users\\smtripat\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\30.0.3\\lib\\apksigner.jar verify --print-certs C:\\Users\\smtripat\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk[debug] [35m[ADB][39m apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87
["io.appium.settings","io.appium.uiautomator2.server","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test"] to Doze whitelist
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Got the following command chunks to execute: [["dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.settings",";","dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.uiautomator2.server",";","dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test",";"]]
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.settings ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test ;'[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting install status for com.android.chrome
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package com.android.chrome'[debug] [35m[ADB][39m 'com.android.chrome' is installed
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.android.chrome'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear com.android.chrome'[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Performed fast reset on the installed 'com.android.chrome' application (stop and clear)
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Performing shallow cleanup of automation leftovers
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m No obsolete sessions have been detected (socket hang up)
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Starting UIAutomator2 server 4.21.1
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Using UIAutomator2 server from 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk' and test from 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","-e","disableAnalytics",true,"io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[info] [35m[WD Proxy][39m socket hang up[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[info] [35m[WD Proxy][39m socket hang up[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[info] [35m[WD Proxy][39m socket hang up
[debug] [35m[Instrumentation][39m io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[info] [35m[WD Proxy][39m socket hang up[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"None","value":{"message":"UiAutomator2 Server is ready to accept commands","ready":true}}
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m The initialization of the instrumentation process took 4185ms
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"Chrome","browserVersion":"83","platformName":"android","appiumVersion":"1.21.0","device":"Android","deviceName":"Pixel_3a_API_30_x86","platformVersion":"11.0"},"browserName":"Chrome","browserVersion":"83","platformName":"android","appiumVersion":"1.21.0","device":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformVersion":"11.0","appPackage":"com.android.chrome","appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554"}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d","value":{"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"Chrome","browserVersion":"83","platformName":"android","appiumVersion":"1.21.0","device":"Android","deviceName":"Pixel_3a_API_30_x86","platformVersion":"11.0"},"browserName":"Chrome","browserVersion":"83","platformName":"android","appiumVersion":"1.21.0","device":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformVersion":"11.0","appPackage":"com.android.chrome","appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554"}],"alwaysMatch":{}},"sessionId":"83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d"}}
[info] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Determined the downstream protocol as 'W3C'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /appium/device/info] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d/appium/device/info] with no body[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d","value":{"androidId":"8ac880deb347dc69","apiVersion":"30","bluetooth":{"state":"ON"},"brand":"google","carrierName":"Android","displayDensity":440,"locale":"en_US","manufacturer":"Google","model":"sdk_gphone_x86_arm","networks":[{"capabilities":{"SSID":null,"linkDownBandwidthKbps":141000,"linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps":141000,"networkCapabilities":"NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED,NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED,NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_ROAMING,NET_CAPABILITY_FOREGROUND,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_CONGESTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED","signalStrength":-30,"transportTypes":"TRANSPORT_WIFI"},"detailedState":"CONNECTED","extraInfo":"","isAvailable":true,"isConnected":true,"isFailover":false,"isRoaming":false,"state":"CONNECTED","subtype":0,"subtypeName":"","type":1,"typeName":"WIFI"},{"capabilities":{"SSID":null,"linkDownBandwidthKbps":30000,"linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps":15000,"networkCapabilities":"NET_CAPABILITY_M...
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys window'
[info] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[info] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Starting a chrome-based browser session
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m A port was not given, using random free port: 8001
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Precalculated Chromedriver capabilities: {
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m   "androidPackage": "com.android.chrome",
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m   "androidDeviceSerial": "emulator-5554"
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m }
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Before starting chromedriver, androidPackage is 'com.android.chrome'
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Changed state to 'starting'
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Using the static Chromedriver->Chrome mapping
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m The most recent known Chrome version: 89.0.4389
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Found 2 executables in 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win'[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m The following Chromedriver executables were found:
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/smtripat/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver_win32_v89.0.4389.23.exe' (version '89.0.4389.23', minimum Chrome version '89.0.4389')
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/smtripat/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe' (version '83.0.4103.14', minimum Chrome version '83')
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Found 1 Chromedriver, which is missing in the list of known versions: {"83.0.4103.14":"83"}
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting package info for 'com.android.chrome'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package com.android.chrome'[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Set chromedriver binary as: C:/Users/smtripat/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Killing any old chromedrivers, running: wmic process where "commandline like '%chromedriver.exe%--port=8001%'" delete[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Successfully cleaned up old chromedrivers
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Cleaning this device's adb forwarded port socket connections: emulator-5554
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m List forwarding ports
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\smtripat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --list'
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Spawning chromedriver with: C:/Users/smtripat/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe --url-base=wd/hub --port=8001 --adb-port=5037 --verbose
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Chromedriver version: '83.0.4103.14'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/wd/hub/status] with no body[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"value":{"build":{"version":"83.0.4103.14 (be04594a2b8411758b860104bc0a1033417178be-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#119})"},"message":"ChromeDriver ready for new sessions.","os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Windows NT","version":"10.0.19042"},"ready":true}}
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Starting W3C Chromedriver session with capabilities: {
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m   "capabilities": {
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     "alwaysMatch": {
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m       "goog:chromeOptions": {
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m         "androidPackage": "com.android.chrome",
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m         "androidDeviceSerial": "emulator-5554"
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m       },
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m       "goog:loggingPrefs": {
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m         "browser": "ALL"
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m       }
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     }
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m   }
[info] [35m[Chromedriver][39m }
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/wd/hub/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"goog:chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"emulator-5554"},"goog:loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL"}}}}[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"value":{"capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"chrome","browserVersion":"83.0.4103.106","chrome":{"chromedriverVersion":"83.0.4103.14 (be04594a2b8411758b860104bc0a1033417178be-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#119})"},"goog:chromeOptions":{"debuggerAddress":"localhost:64660"},"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"android","proxy":{},"setWindowRect":false,"strictFileInteractability":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"unhandledPromptBehavior":"dismiss and notify","webauthn:virtualAuthenticators":false},"sessionId":"1e5c9be243820b880113375b22ec11ba"}}
[info] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Determined the downstream protocol as 'W3C'
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Changed state to 'online'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /appium/device/pixel_ratio] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d/appium/device/pixel_ratio] with no body
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d","value":2.75}
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/appium/device/system_bars' to command name 'getSystemBars'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /appium/device/system_bars] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d/appium/device/system_bars] with no body
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d","value":{"statusBar":66}}
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d/window/current/size] with no body
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"83fc02b0-8571-4d8d-bbef-9f657662004d","value":{"height":2088,"width":1080}}
[info] [35m[Appium][39m New AndroidUiautomator2Driver session created successfully, session b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2 added to master session list
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1624370616730 (09:03:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[debug] [35m[W3C (b58995e6)][39m Cached the protocol value 'W3C' for the new session b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2
[debug] [35m[W3C (b58995e6)][39m Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"capabilities":{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"Chrome","browserVersion":"83","platformName":"android","appiumVersion":"1.21.0","device":"Android","deviceName":"Pixel_3a_API_30_x86","platformVersion":"11.0"},"browserName":"Chrome","browserVersion":"83","platformName":"android","appiumVersion":"1.21.0","device":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformVersion":"11","appPackage":"com.android.chrome","appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554","deviceApiLevel":30,"deviceScreenSize":"1080x2220","deviceScreenDensity":440,"deviceModel":"sdk_gphone_x86_arm","deviceManufacturer":"Google","pixelRatio":2.75,"statBarHeight":66,"viewportRect":{"left":0,"top":66,"width":1080,"height":2022}}}
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[32m200[39m [90m17633 ms - 981[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/timeouts[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"implicit":30000}[39m
[info] [35m[W3C (b58995e6)][39m Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/timeouts' to command name 'timeouts'
[debug] [35m[Protocol Converter][39m Will send the following request bodies to /timeouts: [{"implicit":30000}]
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/timeouts] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/wd/hub/session/1e5c9be243820b880113375b22ec11ba/timeouts] with body: {"implicit":30000}
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"value":null}
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/timeouts [39m[32m200[39m [90m10 ms - 14[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mDELETE[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/cookie[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{}[39m
[info] [35m[W3C (b58995e6)][39m Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/cookie' to command name 'deleteCookies'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [DELETE /wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/cookie] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8001/wd/hub/session/1e5c9be243820b880113375b22ec11ba/cookie] with body: {}
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"value":null}
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/cookie [39m[32m200[39m [90m85 ms - 14[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/url[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"url":"https://consumer-travel-qa.americanexpress.com"}[39m
[info] [35m[W3C (b58995e6)][39m Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/url' to command name 'setUrl'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/b58995e6-e1ad-477a-b7d1-a1087ebef0a2/url] to [POST
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked with switching off the wi-fi and enabling the APN in emulator